# 83%health , not charging , 0 mA current flow , IDLE STATE

Tags: battery

My laptop(DELL INSPIRON 15 series 7567) stuck at 20% battery,showing that "plugged in and charging" but turning off if i remove the charging cable.I ran some diagnatic test for mine and my friends laptop(both of us r using same model).
ill give u the screen shots of them.
CAN U GUYS PLS HELP ME WITH THIS PROBLEM ASAP!!!
my laptop screenshot:
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LPQ2BUFXc5Wkvd0PnajKNJh2R071QLN8
my friends laptop screenshot:
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QkM6Ca19kZlM6Bkc-OyKw448ZWSc7KTE

Comment: Please don't post your image using external sites. Use the image posting functions provided here.

Comment: Buy a new battery.

Comment: Links are dead, and please fix your spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that your battery needs replacement.

I can see another difference between the two computers, where your fans are going
full-blast while your friend's are idle, and this when
there is not any kind of load on your computer and the temperature is not
high at all.

The computer seems to have some issues. It may need, in addition to a new battery,
also the attention of a professional.